# How to update values of dropdown using another dropdown with AJAX nodejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I have two dropdowns. One is for selecting the Main category, the second for selecting the sub category.
I want to be able to populate the sub category based on the Main category selected.

What I have tried so far is using JQUERY and AJAX to listen to change in the value of the dropdown using jquery and send an ajax request to the relevant route.

**View**

```
                     <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="category">Category</label>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value='Men'>Men</option>
                            <option value='Women'>Women</option>
                            <option value='Sports'>Sports</option>
                           
                        </select>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="subcategory">Sub Category</label>
                        <select id="subcategory" name="subcategory">
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

**AJAX and JQUERY**

```
$("#category").on("change", function () {
    $("#subcategory").empty();
    showValue($(this).val());
});
var data = {};

function showValue(val) {
    console.log(val);
    data.category = val;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/update-list",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(result) {

        updateDOM(result);
        },
        error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        }
    });
};

var updateDOM = function (result) {
    
    var data = result.data;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i]);
        $("#subcategory").append("<option>"+ data[i] +"</option>");
    };
   
    };
```

**/admin/update-list  Route**

```
router.post('/update-list', (req,res,next) => {
  let data = [];
  let category = req.body.category;
 

  console.log('From the ajax call, category is' + category);


  if(category = "Men") {
    data = [
      'Sneakers',
      'Boots',
      'High Heels',
      'Litas',
      'Timbs'
    ];
    res.status(200).json({data});
    res.end();
  }
  else if(category = "Women") {
    data = [ 
      'Timbs'
    ];
     res.status(200).json({data});
     res.end();
  }
   else if(category = "Sports") {
    data = [ 
      'Soccer Boots',
      'Rugby Boots'
    ];
     res.status(200).json({data});
     res.end();
  }



});
```

No matter what option I choose, the second dropdown returns the same data.

Comment: Is the page you are using to get the option values PHP?

Comment: No. I'm using EJS

Comment: I do this all the time using PHP but not EJS. I am afraid I won't be able to help. In PHP I replace the select on the DOM with the new select that is built in the post back. Then I don't have to bother with appending or changing the existing options.

Comment: It might help. Just post your answer

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in PHP. Hopefully this conveys what you could adapt to your situation:

```
<select name="foo" >

</select>
```

ajax call

```
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'your_code_page.php',
            data:'param1='+variable,
            success:function(html){
                $('[name="foo"]').html(html);
            }
        });
```

PHP post back

```
  echo "<option value=''>Please select a thing</option>"; <<outside loop
                        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results)) {
                            $value   = $row['value'];
                            $display = $row['display'];
                            //-display the result of the array 
                            

       echo "<option value= " . $value . ">" . $display . "</option>"; << options returned in post


                        }
```